# Show that $\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3)\sin(tx)\,dx$ converges uniformly for $t$ in any finite interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I've spent the last few hrs racking my head about how to solve this problem.

Show that

$$\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3)\sin(tx)\,dx$$

converges uniformly for $t$ in any finite interval

So far I've managed to derive the following:

$$\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3)\sin(tx)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{2}\big(\cos(tx-x^3)-\cos(tx+x^3)\big)\,dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{e^{i(tx-x^3)}+e^{i(x^3-tx)}}{2}-\frac{e^{i(tx+x^3)}+e^{-i(tx+x^3)}}{2}\right)dx$$

From here, my strategy was to separate the integrals and then try to manipulate them into the gamma function as follows. On the first integral I had:

Let $u=-x^2\Rightarrow x=iu^{1/2}\Rightarrow i(tx-x^3)=-tu^{1/2}-u^{3/2}$

$$\frac{du}{-2x}=dx\Rightarrow\frac{1}{8}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-tu^{1/2}-u^{3/2}}du$$

However, after this I don't know how to continue. I don't think this approach is fruitless, but I can't figure it out at this time. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just integrate by parts* repeatedly. For $a>0$ we have
$$
I(a,t):=\int_a^\infty x\sin x^3\sin tx\,dx
=-\frac13\int_a^\infty(\cos x^3)'\frac{\sin tx}{x}\,dx
\\=\frac{\cos a^3\sin ta}{3a}
-\frac13\int_a^\infty\frac{\cos x^3\sin tx}{x^2}\,dx
+\frac{t}3J(a,t),
\\
J(a,t):=\int_a^\infty\frac{\cos x^3\cos tx}{x}\,dx
=\frac13\int_a^\infty(\sin x^3)'\frac{\cos tx}{x^3}\,dx
\\=-\frac{\sin a^3\cos ta}{3a^3}
+\frac{t}3\int_a^\infty\frac{\sin x^3\sin tx}{x^3}\,dx
+\int_a^\infty\frac{\sin x^3\cos tx}{x^4}\,dx,
\\
\therefore\qquad
|I(a,t)|\leqslant\frac1{3a}+\frac1{3a}+\frac{|t|}3\left(\frac1{3a^3}+\frac{|t|}{6a^2}+\frac1{3a^3}\right),
$$
and the estimate clearly converges to $0$ (as $a\to\infty$) uniformly for $t$ in any finite interval.